# File bit error vs. smartcl -t long /dev/sda vs. faulty RAM

Tags: disk, smartctl

Just by luck, trying to measure some disk access times, I found a file that was written with all zeros to contain a nonzero byte on my SSD.

I kept the file and did the same trials with new files and could not find any more nonzero bytes.

Then I deleted all files and started over, only to again find a nonzero byte in one of the files.

Then I ran `smartctl -t long`. Since I read it tests the whole "surface", I thought for an SSD this would mean to write/read each byte and expected a failure mentioned somewhere, but I could not find any.

In the end it could still be a RAM error, I assume, since all bytes written pass through the RAM.

If I want to verify that there is that bit stuck on the disk rather than having a flaky RAM, do I have a chance to prove it with `smartctl` somehow?

Comment: I think the SMART tests depend entirely on what the drive in question bothers to do. If the test implementation just tests that it gets some internally consistent data out of the drive, it could mask some errors. Spinning disks can a fail a self test due to a read error, but then work again after rewriting the affected part, either because the rewrite actually fixes it in-place, or the drive reallocates the sector elsewhere. And SSDs are way more aggressive at shuffling data around.

Comment: You could run something like `badblocks` on the drive, but as it's an SSD, you probably can't test all of the actual flash with regular tools. On the other hand, memory issues would show up elsewhere, too, and Memtest86 and Memtest86+ are pretty good at finding them. So you can rule out that first. In the end, I don't think there's a good way to definitively locate hardware problems, other than swapping out parts and finding the one that's always present when a problem appears. And what you do when you find that part is up to you, but I'd suggest recycling and buying a new one, in general..

Comment: I'd start with memtest, because it doesn't materially affect write cycles

Answer (score 1):

I could just delete my question, but the way it is phrased the following is an answer, according advice from @likkachu in the comments. And a warning to others to not jump to conclusions, as I did, assuming to quick it might be the disk.

It was a **flaky RAM** and as suggested in the comments, running a memory tester was most likely easier than trying to prove the SSD being faulty. I used

- memtester (available on ubuntu and probably other distros) to quickly show that there is some problem with the RAM. I could not figure out which physical address it is with memtester.
- Due to UEFI booting, memtest86+ turned out to be difficult to get going, so I used `dd` to put a memtest86 image on a USB and ran it. It gave me a physical address. But actually the easiest was:
- Add the parameter memtest (or memtest=n where n is in [1..17]) as a kernel boot parameter, e.g. for a single boot by editing the boot parameters in grub (ESC to get into grub for EFI, if the menu is skipped normally).

The kernel found the flaky address, see `/var/log/kern.log` for something like

```
 bad mem addr 0x00000000a31b7320 - 0x00000000a31b7328 reserved
```

I then added

```
GRUB_BADRAM="0x0a31b7320,0xffffffff0"
```

to `/etc/default/grub` and ran `update-grub`. Note that the mask has 9 digits. With 8 digits, this would apply to each 4GB block of RAM.

After booting, `/var/log/kern.log` contained

```
reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000a31b7000-0x00000000a31b7fff] unusable
```

which shows that either grub or the kernel rounded the mask to a full page of 4096 bytes, meaning it does not harm to be too specific in the `GRUB_BADRAM` mask. Running `memtester` again, no problem was found anymore.